# SQL return date from function gets an error in setting variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the error "Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator." in line 6 where i set the dummy variable.

When i remove the first part there is no error, so i think the setting of the variable also tries to execute some of the functions in the string.

Is is possible to set a variable with functions without having the setting also trying to execute the functions? Or should this be done in an entirely different way?

All i want is the option to use dbo.TimeInterval(7) (or something like this) instead of "`REPLACE([US-Date],'-','') between CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-7,112)) and CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112))`" when i want the time interval of 7 days from today...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TimeInterval(@Input VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @dummy VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @dummy = 'REPLACE([US-Date],'-','') between CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-Tidsinterval,112)) and CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112))'
    SET @dummy = REPLACE(@dummy, 'Tidsinterval',@Input)
    RETURN @dummy
END
```

Comment: Escape your quotes.

Comment: Use DateAdd instead not - operator. BTW your function is questionable, you better use date times for comparison.

Comment: It is seen as `REPLACE([US-Date],` - `,') between..` and you cannot subtract varchar values

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Ah yes of course! How do i declare it, so it takes in the entire string? Parenthesis doesnt work for me..

Comment: Double the quotes to escape them: `'REPLACE([US-Date],''-'','''') ...`